# ASP.NET ModelState.IsValid is validating returnUrl parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've already spent hours finding someone with the same issue, by Googling and it seems like nobody else has the same issue. So I am creating my first post here :)

I have a method inside a controller, which is supposed to log-in the user and afterwards redirect the user to the url which he was previously trying to reach. But `ModelState.IsValid` is not only validating the model, but also the `url` parameter and if the user is NOT trying to get redirected (user is at the 'root-page' and clicks the button to login - in other words the `returnUrl` is null) and then it would always tell me that the validation is unsuccessful.

I do not want to remove this error all the time manually, but find a different solution, where it would not try to validate this parameter.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([Bind("Email,Password")] LoginViewModel data, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
         return View(data);

    // todo throw custom error if user does not exist
    ClassUser? user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == data.Email);
    //...
}
```

[Click here to see ModelState's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Ecj.png)

Thank you very much in advance. I've been trying for hours to solve this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a question mark at the end of your last parameter datatype like this **`string? returnUrl`** or try **`Nullable<string> returnUrl`**

Comment: oh my god... *facepalm* 
why didn't I think about that...Thank you so much♥..how can i put your answer as the accepted one?

Comment: I am glad to hear that it helps. You can just click on the tick on the left to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve this issue

1- Changing the OnGetAsync parameter

from

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
```

to

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string? returnUrl = null)
```

2- Ignore returnUrl from ModelState

```
ModelState.Remove("returnUrl");
```